Lagrange mutilplier and KKT theorem problem(maybe) with some probabilities
Suppose we want to maximise a expected utility function: $$E_1(u(C_1,C_2,C_3))
$$ subject to following constraints. There are two possible situations each with probability $\frac{1}{2}$.
$$C_1 + S_1 = Y
$$
\begin{cases}
C_{2,1} + S_{2,1} = Y + S_1 + \varepsilon \\
C_{3,1} = Y + S_{2,1} & \text{with probability } \frac{1}{2}
\end{cases} 
\begin{cases}
C_{2,2} + S_{2,2} = Y + S_1 - \varepsilon \\
C_{3,2} = Y + S_{2,2} & \text{with probability } \frac{1}{2}
\end{cases} 
$C_1, C_{2,1}, C_{2,2}, C_{3,1}, C_{3,2} > 0$.
How can we solve this model using lagrangian, when ignoring the inequality? I have never seen similar models before, so I'm stuck at the beginning of writing a Lagrangian.
Further, if we include liquidity constraint, that $S_1,S_{2,1},S_{2,2}\geq 0$? I can convert these inequality constraints into $Y$ and $\varepsilon$, and use KKT theorem? I really have no idea of it.
Here you can consider $C_i$ as consumption in $i$ time period, $C_{i,j}$ be consumption at $i$ period with $j$ situation(whether add or subtract $\varepsilon$),and $S$ similarly defined.
